# Cannot connect MyBusiness with google-api-php-client

Tags: php, api, google-my-business-api

my goal is to receive the locations of a specific account.

I know the followed all instructions:

1. I downloaded and installed the google client in php
   [API Samples](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client)
2. I downloaded and installed MyBusiness.php from here
   [Business Samples](https://developers.google.com/my-business/samples/)
3. I created the project in the developer console (https://console.developers.google.com)
4. I requested access for Google My Business API and I received confirmation of activation and I enabled the API from the console.
5. I followed the tutorial to receive information about the accounts from which they can retrieve information

Unfortunately I always get the same error and I do not know what to do after hours of testing:
"Request is missing required authentication credential Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookies or another valid authentication credential"

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setHttpClient($httpClient);
$client->setApplicationName("project_id");
$client->setDeveloperKey('DEVELOPER KEY');
$client->setAuthConfig(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'oauth.json');
$client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage");
$service = new Google_Service_Mybusiness($client);
 $accounts = $service->accounts->listAccounts();
```

How can i solve it?

What am i missing?